# GET list of groups from cloudidentity.googleapis.com returns INVALID_ARGUMENT error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-identity

The end goal is to get a list of a user's groups after OAuth Authentication is completed using the supplied access token.

I'm currently having difficulty retrieving a list of groups from the Cloud Identity API after OAuth is completed.

[Cloud Identity - Method: groups.list Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups/list)

Steps:

- Go to [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)
- Enter your own scope at the bottom of the list using 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups.readonly"
- Click "Authorize APIs" button
- Choose the google account to use
- Allow the "Cloud Identity Groups"
- Click "Exchange authorization code for
  tokens" button
- Optionally "Auto-refresh the token before it expires."
- Click "List possible operations" Select "List Groups" - This
  populates the request URI. Click "Send the request"

```
GET /v1/groups HTTP/1.1
Host: cloudidentity.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 127
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: ESF
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 16:12:32 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", 
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

I've only ever been able to get invalid arguments with a status of INVALID_ARGUMENT.
I've tried providing an API key from my own project, adding the parent parameter as required by the documentation.

Can someone please help with a valid request?

I have tried to get this working using the OAuth 2.0 Playground, the 'Try this API' functionality through the documentation and locally using a variety of options, I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Cloud Identity groups API only provides access to *Identity Mapped Groups*, which makes it only relevant in the context of Cloud Search.

To access "regular" groups, use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're passing in a valid value in the `parent` query parameter. The URL should look like:

`https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/groups?parent=customers/**your_customer_id_which_can_be_found_in_the_admin_console**`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you, first you need to pass parent, and also you need to add the prefix for your customer_id.

```
Must be of the form identitysources/{identity_source_id} for external- identity-mapped groups or customers/{customer_id} for Google Groups. The customer_id must begin with "C" (for example, 'C046psxkn').
```

so the url should be really looks like this,

https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/groups?parent=customers/C<customer_id>&access_token=<oauth_token>